# Implicit class with overloaded method and lambda parameter

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to wrap a Java API of a library in multiple Scala-friendly ways. So the base API looks like this:

```scala
  trait Keyer[K]

  class Base[T] {
    def keyBy[K](keyer: Keyer[K]): Base[K] = ???
  }
```

We want to add a lambda method, so we don't need to write `new Keyer[K] { def ??? }` all the time. Extending the base class works:

```scala
  class Child[T] extends Base[T] {
    def keyBy[K](fun: T => K): Base[K] = ???
  }

  new Child[Int].keyBy(x => x) // no issues so far
```

But doing similar thing using implicit classes fails:

```scala
  trait ChildOps[T] {
    def keyBy[K](fun: T => K): Base[K] = ???
  }

  implicit class BaseOps[T](base: Base[T]) extends ChildOps[T]

  new Base[Int].keyBy(x => x) // compile error: missing parameter type
```

I also tried to move the `keyBy` method directly to the implicit class without extending anything, but the compile error is still there:

```scala
  implicit class BaseOps2[T](base: Base[T]) {
    def keyBy[K](fun: T => K): Base[K] = ???
  }

  new Base[Int].keyBy(x => x) // compile error: missing parameter type
```

Giving up and annotating `keyBy` method with types is also problematic:

```scala
  implicit class BaseOps2[T](base: Base[T]) {
    def keyBy[K](fun: T => K): Base[K] = ???
  }

  new Base[Int].keyBy[Int]((x: Int) => x)
// type mismatch;
// found   : Int => Int
// required: com.test.ImplicitTest.Keyer[Int]
//  new Base[Int].keyBy[Int]((x: Int) => x)
```

So the question is: how can I add a generic overridden method with lambda parameter in an implicit class? And why all my attempts above giving a compile errors?

Code fails on Scala 2.13.8 and 2.12.15, but compiles successfully on 3.1.2.

Comment: I couldn't find the documentation to explain *why*, but I believe in Scala 2.x, if the subject class already has a method with the name you're asking for (`keyBy`), it will not search for implicit conversions to satisfy a different type signature. In short, you can't overload `keyBy` with implicit classes. You'll need to call it something else, like `keyByF`